# How to deploy mongodb on EC2 using API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, amazon-ec2

For a project in node.js i want to deploy mongodb instance on amazon ec2 using amazon api or something like that, is it possible? i found nothing about that.

Thanks for the time

Comment: User data script can be used to initialize you amazon server. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=378766

Comment: yes but nothing exist for deploy the instance?

Comment: I disagree, there are loads and loads of tools for calling the amazon API. One example is terraform: https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1. vagrant with the aws provider
2. terraform as mentioned
3. cloudformation
4. using AWSCLI (and userdata): `$ aws ec2 run-instances help`